# Adding each element in an array by each element in the same array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I need to add each element in an array by each element in the same array and then add the results to a new array. I have tried

```
my_list = []

for filename in [my_file]:
    with open(filename) as f:
        my_list += [int(i) for line in f for i in line.split()]

answer = []

for elem in my_list:
    answer += [elem + elem]

print answer
```

When `my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, the program prints `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]` which is incorrect. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @ChristianDean  [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,...] it's just basic math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

answer = [i+a for i in my_list for a in my_list]
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```